# What does the derivative of tangent means?

Tags: kinematics, differential-geometry, vectors, differentiation

While studying the circular motion I had to find the derivative of a tangent so I thought what the derivative of a tangent could probably mean since the derivative of position gives velocity.
Or think like finding tangent of a tangent.
Or instantaneous rate of change of tangent in a circular motion.

Comment: Can you provide source?

Comment: Are you asking for a geometric interpretation of $\frac{d}{d\theta}\tan\theta=\sec^2\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

If derivative of the tangent (as a vector) gives the velocity, the derivativ of this velocity is the acceleration, without physics it gives the change of direction  (and  magnitude) of the tangen.